# no rollback when using Spring, JOOQ, Postgres, and ActiveMQ

Tags: spring, postgresql, activemq-classic, jooq, atomikos

Database writes are not rolling back as I expected.
I've spent many hours reading software documentation and web postings.
I have not been able to resolve the issue.

I'm hoping you folks can help me.

Scenario

- My application pulls a message from a queue, extracts data from the
  message, and writes it to a database.
- The method that writes to the database does 2 SQL inserts.
- The second insert gets an exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "table2_PK"
- However, the first insert is still getting committed to the database.

Relevant Software

1. spring-boot 1.2.5.RELEASE
2. atomikos-util 3.9.3 (from spring-boot-starter-jta-atomikos 1.2.5.RELEASE)
3. jooq 3.6.2
4. postgresql 9.4-1201-jdbc41
5. activemq-client 5.1.2

Application Code - I've pasted the relevant parts of my code below.

1. GdmServer - my "server" class, which also declares Spring bean
   configurations
2. PortSIQueue - my JMS MessageListener class
3. Kernel - my worker class, i.e. the code that writes to database, a Spring bean invoked by my MessageListener

I'd appreciate any help anyone can offer.

Thanks

---

```
package com.sm.gis.gdm;

import javax.transaction.SystemException;
import javax.transaction.UserTransaction;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory;
import org.jooq.DSLContext;
import org.jooq.SQLDialect;
import org.jooq.impl.DSL;
import org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.jta.atomikos.AtomikosDataSourceBean;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager;

import com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp;
import com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager;
import com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean;
import com.sm.gis.config.GisConfig;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class GdmServer {

    @Autowired
    ConfigurableApplicationContext  context;
    @Autowired
    GisConfig                       gisConfig;

    /**
     * Starts the GDM Server
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GdmServer.class, args);
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Spring bean configurations
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    @Bean
    GisConfig gisConfig() {
        return new GisConfig();
    }

    @Bean
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws SystemException {
        JtaTransactionManager manager = new JtaTransactionManager();
        manager.setTransactionManager( atomikosUserTransactionManager() );
        manager.setUserTransaction   ( atomikosUserTransaction() );
        manager.setAllowCustomIsolationLevels(true);
        return manager;
    }

    @Bean(initMethod = "init", destroyMethod = "close")
    UserTransactionManager atomikosUserTransactionManager() throws SystemException {
        UserTransactionManager manager = new UserTransactionManager();
        manager.setStartupTransactionService(true);
        manager.setForceShutdown(false);
        manager.setTransactionTimeout( gisConfig.getTxnTimeout() );
        return manager;
    }

    @Bean
    UserTransaction atomikosUserTransaction() {
        return new UserTransactionImp();
    }

    @Bean(initMethod = "init", destroyMethod = "close")
    AtomikosDataSourceBean atomikosJdbcConnectionFactory() {
        PGXADataSource pgXADataSource = new PGXADataSource();
        pgXADataSource.setUrl( gisConfig.getGdbUrl() );
        pgXADataSource.setUser( gisConfig.getGdbUser() );
        pgXADataSource.setPassword( gisConfig.getGdbPassword() );

        AtomikosDataSourceBean xaDataSource = new AtomikosDataSourceBean();
        xaDataSource.setXaDataSource(pgXADataSource);
        xaDataSource.setUniqueResourceName("gdb");
        xaDataSource.setPoolSize( gisConfig.getGdbPoolSize() );
        return xaDataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    DSLContext dslContext() {
        DSLContext dslContext = DSL.using(atomikosJdbcConnectionFactory(), SQLDialect.POSTGRES);
        return dslContext;
    }

    @Bean(initMethod = "init", destroyMethod = "close")
    AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean atomikosJmsConnectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory activeMQXAConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory();
        activeMQXAConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL( gisConfig.getMomBrokerUrl() );

        AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean atomikosConnectionFactoryBean = new AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean();
        atomikosConnectionFactoryBean.setUniqueResourceName("activeMQBroker");
        atomikosConnectionFactoryBean.setXaConnectionFactory(activeMQXAConnectionFactory);
        atomikosConnectionFactoryBean.setLocalTransactionMode(false);
        return atomikosConnectionFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer queueWrapperGDM() throws SystemException {
        DefaultMessageListenerContainer messageSource = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
        messageSource.setTransactionManager( transactionManager() );
        messageSource.setConnectionFactory( atomikosJmsConnectionFactory() );
        messageSource.setSessionTransacted(true);
        messageSource.setConcurrentConsumers(1);
        messageSource.setReceiveTimeout( gisConfig.getMomQueueGdmTimeoutReceive() );
        messageSource.setDestinationName( gisConfig.getMomQueueGdmName() );
        messageSource.setMessageListener( context.getBean("portSIQueue") );
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    JmsTemplate queueWrapperLIMS() {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
        jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory( atomikosJmsConnectionFactory() );
        jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestinationName( gisConfig.getMomQueueLimsName() );
        jmsTemplate.setSessionTransacted(true);
        return jmsTemplate;
    }

}
```

---

```
package com.sm.gis.gdm.ports;

import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.sm.gis.gdm.kernel.Kernel;
import com.sm.gis.sdo.xml.marshaler.GisMessageMarshaler;
import com.sm.gis.sdo.xml.service.message.CreateGenomicTestOrderInGIS;

@Component
public class PortSIQueue implements MessageListener {

    @Autowired
    ConfigurableApplicationContext  context;
    @Autowired
    GisMessageMarshaler             queueMessageMashaler;
    @Autowired
    Kernel                          kernel;

    @Override
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = {Throwable.class})
    public void onMessage(Message jmsMessage) {

        TextMessage jmsTextMessage = (TextMessage) jmsMessage;

        // Extract JMS message body...
        String jmsPayload = "";
        try {
            jmsPayload = jmsTextMessage.getText();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        // Marshal XML text to object...
        Object gisMessage = queueMessageMashaler.toObject(jmsPayload);

        kernel.receiveCreateGenomicTestOrderInGIS( (CreateGenomicTestOrderInGIS) gisMessage );
    }

}
```

---

```
package com.sm.gis.gdm.kernel;

import org.jooq.DSLContext;
import org.jooq.impl.DSL;

@Component
public class Kernel {

    @Autowired
    ConfigurableApplicationContext  context;
    @Autowired
    DSLContext                      dslContext;

<snip>
    public void receiveCreateGenomicTestOrderInGIS(CreateGenomicTestOrderInGIS message) {

            dslContext.insertInto(table1)
                .set(...)
                .set(...)
            .execute();

            dslContext.insertInto(table2)
                .set(...)
                .set(...)
            .execute();
    }
<snip>
}
```

---

Comment: Why are you trying hard to not use Spring Boot? Spring Boot 1.2 has JTA support and auto detection for Atomikos out-of-the-box. You are trying very hard not to use and circumvent Spring Boot work with a framework not against it.

Comment: [For the record, this is also being discussed on the jOOQ User Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jooq-user/geYotcwEcRM)

Comment: I'm not trying circumvent Sprint Boot. I believe I've followed the instructions for using Spring Boot 1.2 and Atomikos as described by the Spring documentation and the relevant material on the Atomkos, JOOQ, and ActiveMQ web sites. That said, I'm not trying to create create trouble for anyone, or me. :) Perhaps I've misunderstood something. That's why I've posted the question.

Comment: I suspect that your exception translator might be wrong. Could you post that as well, please?

Answer (score 1):

I'm an idiot.
Turns out the issue was due to a defect in my application logic.
The ActiveMQ component retries a message if the first attempt to process the message fails with an exception. The transaction created for the first attempt rolled back correctly. It was the second attempt that succeeded. The retry succeeded because a database sequence number was incremented by the application logic during the first attempt, and the second attempt did not result in a duplicate key violation. After correcting the application logic defect, since in my application no message is retry-able anyway, I turned off retry, too.
I apologize for wasting the time of those who read my post.

Along the way, I did make some changes to the implementation. The changes make certain default values explicit choices. I left those changes in because I believe they will make it easier for other developers on my team to understand what's happening more quickly. I also left the JOOQ exception translation code in place because it would be needed in other circumstances and appears to be best practice anyway.

I've included the modified code in this post, in case others might find it useful.

---

```
package com.sm.gis.gdm;

import javax.transaction.SystemException;
import javax.transaction.UserTransaction;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.RedeliveryPolicy;
import org.jooq.DSLContext;
import org.jooq.SQLDialect;
import org.jooq.impl.DefaultConfiguration;
import org.jooq.impl.DefaultDSLContext;
import org.jooq.impl.DefaultExecuteListenerProvider;
import org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.jta.atomikos.AtomikosDataSourceBean;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.DependsOn;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager;

import com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp;
import com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager;
import com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean;
import com.sm.gis.config.GisConfig;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass=true)
public class GdmServer {

    @Autowired
    ConfigurableApplicationContext   context;
    @Autowired
    GisConfig                        gisConfig;

    /**
     * Starts the GDM Server
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GdmServer.class, args);
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Spring bean configurations
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    @Bean
    GisConfig gisConfig() {
        return new GisConfig();
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn({ "atomikosUserTransactionManager", "atomikosUserTransaction", "atomikosJdbcConnectionFactory", "atomikosJmsConnectionFactory" })
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws SystemException {
        JtaTransactionManager manager = new JtaTransactionManager();
        manager.setTransactionManager( atomikosUserTransactionManager() );
        manager.setUserTransaction( atomikosUserTransaction() );
        manager.setAllowCustomIsolationLevels(true);
        manager.afterPropertiesSet();
        return manager;
    }

    @Bean(initMethod = "init", destroyMethod = "close")
    UserTransactionManager atomikosUserTransactionManager() throws SystemException {
        UserTransactionManager manager = new UserTransactionManager();
        manager.setStartupTransactionService(true);
        manager.setForceShutdown(false);
        manager.setTransactionTimeout( gisConfig.getTxnTimeout() );
        return manager;
    }

    @Bean
    UserTransaction atomikosUserTransaction() {
        return new UserTransactionImp();
    }

    @Bean(initMethod = "init", destroyMethod = "close")
    AtomikosDataSourceBean atomikosJdbcConnectionFactory() throws Exception {
        PGXADataSource pgXADataSource = new PGXADataSource();
        pgXADataSource.setUrl( gisConfig.getGdbUrl() );
        pgXADataSource.setUser( gisConfig.getGdbUser() );
        pgXADataSource.setPassword( gisConfig.getGdbPassword() );

        AtomikosDataSourceBean xaDataSource = new AtomikosDataSourceBean();
        xaDataSource.setXaDataSource(pgXADataSource);
        xaDataSource.setUniqueResourceName("gdb");
        xaDataSource.setPoolSize( gisConfig.getGdbPoolSize() );
        xaDataSource.setTestQuery("SELECT 1");
        xaDataSource.afterPropertiesSet();
        return xaDataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn({ "atomikosJdbcConnectionFactory" })
    DSLContext dslContext() throws Exception {
        DefaultConfiguration jooqConfiguration = new DefaultConfiguration();
        jooqConfiguration.set( SQLDialect.POSTGRES_9_4 );
        jooqConfiguration.set( atomikosJdbcConnectionFactory() );
        jooqConfiguration.set( new DefaultExecuteListenerProvider(new JooqToSpringExceptionTransformer()) );
        DSLContext dslContext = new DefaultDSLContext(jooqConfiguration);
        return dslContext;
    }


    @Bean(initMethod = "init", destroyMethod = "close")
    AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean atomikosJmsConnectionFactory() {
        RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy = new RedeliveryPolicy();
        redeliveryPolicy.setInitialRedeliveryDelay(0);
        redeliveryPolicy.setRedeliveryDelay(0);
        redeliveryPolicy.setUseExponentialBackOff(false);
        redeliveryPolicy.setMaximumRedeliveries(0);

        ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory activeMQXAConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory();
        activeMQXAConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL( gisConfig.getMomBrokerUrl() );
        activeMQXAConnectionFactory.setRedeliveryPolicy(redeliveryPolicy);

        AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean atomikosConnectionFactoryBean = new AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean();
        atomikosConnectionFactoryBean.setUniqueResourceName("activeMQBroker");
        atomikosConnectionFactoryBean.setXaConnectionFactory(activeMQXAConnectionFactory);
        atomikosConnectionFactoryBean.setLocalTransactionMode(false);
        return atomikosConnectionFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn({ "transactionManager" })
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer queueWrapperGDM() throws SystemException {
        DefaultMessageListenerContainer messageSource = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
        messageSource.setTransactionManager( transactionManager() );
        messageSource.setConnectionFactory( atomikosJmsConnectionFactory() );
        messageSource.setSessionTransacted(true);
        messageSource.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(0);
        messageSource.setConcurrentConsumers(1);
        messageSource.setReceiveTimeout( gisConfig.getMomQueueGdmTimeoutReceive() );
        messageSource.setDestinationName( gisConfig.getMomQueueGdmName() );
        messageSource.setMessageListener( context.getBean("portSIQueue") );
        messageSource.afterPropertiesSet();
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn({ "transactionManager" })
    JmsTemplate queueWrapperLIMS() {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
        jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory( atomikosJmsConnectionFactory() );
        jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestinationName( gisConfig.getMomQueueLimsName() );
        jmsTemplate.setSessionTransacted(true);
        jmsTemplate.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(0);
        return jmsTemplate;
    }

}
```

---

```
package com.sm.gis.gdm.ports;

import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.sm.gis.gdm.kernel.Kernel;
import com.sm.gis.sdo.xml.marshaler.GisMessageMarshaler;
import com.sm.gis.sdo.xml.service.message.CreateGenomicTestOrderInGIS;

@Component
public class PortSIQueue implements MessageListener {

    @Autowired
    ConfigurableApplicationContext    context;
    @Autowired
    GisMessageMarshaler               queueMessageMashaler;
    @Autowired
    Kernel                            kernel;

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = {Throwable.class})
    public void onMessage(Message jmsMessage) {

        TextMessage jmsTextMessage = (TextMessage) jmsMessage;

        // Extract JMS message body...
        String jmsPayload = "";
        try {
            jmsPayload = jmsTextMessage.getText();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        // Marshal XML text to object...
        Object gisMessage = queueMessageMashaler.toObject(jmsPayload);

        kernel.receiveCreateGenomicTestOrderInGIS( (CreateGenomicTestOrderInGIS) gisMessage );

}
```

---

```
package com.sm.gis.gdm.kernel;

import org.jooq.DSLContext;

@Component
public class Kernel {

    @Autowired
    ConfigurableApplicationContext  context;
    @Autowired
    DSLContext                      dslContext;

<snip>
    public void receiveCreateGenomicTestOrderInGIS(CreateGenomicTestOrderInGIS message) {

        dslContext.insertInto(table1)
            .set(...)
            .set(...)
        .execute();

        dslContext.insertInto(table2)
            .set(...)
            .set(...)
        .execute();
    }
<snip>
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issues using the Transactional Annotation. Had to explicitly handle transactions using (begin..commit)/rollback in try/catch. Not very elegant and repetitive but works. TransactionContext is saved in the current thread. so your begin method does not need to return the ctx object. TransactionContext can be instantiated using your DSLContext.configuration().

public class DataSourceTransactionProvider implements TransactionProvider {
    private final DataSourceTransactionManager txMgr;

```
@Inject
public DataSourceTransactionProvider(DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager) {
    this.txMgr = transactionManager;
}

@Override
public void begin(TransactionContext ctx) throws DataAccessException {
    TransactionStatus transactionStatus = txMgr.getTransaction(new DefaultTransactionDefinition(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_NESTED));
    ctx.transaction(new DBTransaction(transactionStatus));
}

@Override
public void commit(TransactionContext ctx) throws DataAccessException {
    txMgr.commit(((DBTransaction) ctx.transaction()).transactionStatus);
}

@Override
public void rollback(TransactionContext ctx) throws DataAccessException {
    txMgr.rollback(((DBTransaction) ctx.transaction()).transactionStatus);
}
```

}